# Route to different View(use @Html.ActionLink and ng-view in View) in Asp.Net MVC with AngularJS, ng-view only work one time, location url strange

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, routes, html.actionlink, ng-view

In my case, I need use **@Html.ActionLink** to Route to different View with AngularJS.In each view1/index.cshtml in asp.net has `<div ng-view></div>` that will load its html template.

the following link image is my project structure:
[**click**](http://seventw.com/stack-image/projectStructure.png)

My problem is: it only route success first time.I think it cause wrong location url.

**Views/Share/_Layout.cshtml:**

```
<ul>
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Device Management", "Index", "DeviceManagement")</li>
</ul>
```

**Views/Home/index.cshtml:**

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
    ViewBag.InitModule = "homeIndex";
}
@section Scripts {
    <script src="~/app/home/homeIndex.js"></script>
}
<div ng-view><div>
```

**app/home/homeIndex.js**

```
var homeIndex = angular.module('homeIndex', ["ngRoute"]);

homeIndex.config(["$routeProvider", function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
        .when("/home",{
            templateUrl:"app/home/homeIndex.html",
            controller:"homeCtrl"

        })

        .otherwise({
            redirectTo:"/home"
        });
}]);
```

**app/home/homeIndex.html**

```
<a href="#/home2">HOME2</a>
```

**app/deviceManagement/deviceManageIndex.js**

```
var deviceManageIndex = angular.module('deviceManageIndex', ["ngRoute"]);

deviceManageIndex.config(["$routeProvider", function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when("/device", {
            templateUrl: "app/deviceManagement/deviceManagementIndex.html",
            controller: "deviceManageCtrl"

        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo:"/device"
        });

}]);
```

the web site has sidebar, *Home* and *Device Management* Buttons in the sidebar.

when I click *Home*, it will redirect right location, it can load homeIndex.html successful:

location is:

```
http://localhost:13060/#/home
```

but when I click *Home* Button second time, it can't load homeIndex.html anymore.

location will change to:

```
http://localhost:13060/#
```

the same problem is happened in another Button *Device Management*

when I click *Device Management*, it will redirect right location, it can load deviceManagementIndex.html successful:

location is:

```
http://localhost:13060/DeviceManagement#/device
```

but when I click *Device Management* Button second time, it can't load deviceManagementIndex.html anymore.

location will change to:

```
http://localhost:13060/DeviceManagement#
```

I think the location is quite strange,in first time,it should be :

```
http://localhost:13060/DeviceManagement/#/device
```

I guess that is main reason not to load html template correctly...

But why the location url can't show correctly, Please Help me solve the headache problem....

Comment: Who can save me,,,Help :'0

Comment: The routing is client-side only, It will not redirect to a raw URL. Maybe I misread it, but I think you'll need to handle it as a callback and then use $window.location to set it manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to  Shawn tip!In my case, I should use angular routing in client  side, `$routeProvider` with `templateUrl` to trigger servier side controller to load server side View,That's I found solution, in this way actionlink behavior could through server side, it will follow server side route rule to chose appropriate View. It shoud be work...:D