# What happened on location url when click @Html.ActionLink more than twice?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4, ngroute

According to:

[Route to different View(use @Html.ActionLink and ng-view in View) in Asp.Net MVC with AngularJS, ng-view only work one time, location url strange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29074401/route-to-different-viewuse-html-actionlink-and-ng-view-in-view-in-asp-net-mvc)

```
<ul>
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Device Management", "Index", "DeviceManagement")</li>
</ul>
```

if I click Device Management first time, the location is:(with ngRoute to "/device" success!)

```
http://localhost:13060/DeviceManagement#/device
```

if I click again Device Management, the location is:(with ngRoute to "/device" can't work!)

```
http://localhost:13060/DeviceManagement#
```

why "/device" will disappear when I click @Html.ActionLink above twice?

what happened @Html.ActionLink did?

Comment: Sound like you're mixing two technologies in a way that's not compatible.  What does your angular routing config look like?

Comment: Hi, I used `<html lang="en" data-ng-app="@ViewBag.InitModule">
` in `_Layout.cshtml`, to produce dynamic multi ng-app, each asp view mapping to different ng-app. In each ng-app, I use ng-route to route to sub page.other routing config please check:[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29074401/route-to-different-viewuse-html-actionlink-and-ng-view-in-view-in-asp-net-mvc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, it should route with angular route in client side.Action link should be modified:

```
<a href="/#/home">Home</a>
<a href="/#/devicemanagement">Device Management</a>
```